# Web2py testing with Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web2py

basic question here. I'm following a great tutorial on creating a web2py app by [Marco Laspe] (http://killer-web-development.com). But struggling with resolving a failure in my testing (using Selenium).

here is my about page...

```
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>aaa</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>blah</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the testing function...

```
def test_has_right_title(self):
    title = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('title')
    self.assertEqual('aaa', title.text)
```

WHen testing i get...

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_has_right_title (test_static_pages.TestPrivacyPage)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\web2py\applications\pitch\fts\test_static_pages.py", line 40, in test
_has_right_title
    self.assertEqual('aaa', title.text)
AssertionError: 'aaa' != u''

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 37.497s

FAILED (failures=3)
```

Anyone know where i'm going wrong? The other tests are working correctly (included below)

```
def setUp(self):
    self.url = ROOT + '/pitch/default/privacy'
    get_browser=self.browser.get(self.url)

def test_can_view_privacy_page(self):
    response_code = self.get_response_code(self.url)
    self.assertEqual(response_code, 200)

def test_has_right_heading(self):        
    heading = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('h1')
    self.assertIn('Pitch.Me Privacy Policy', heading.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting the tag, the Selenium API provides a function in the `Driver` class to get the title.  Try..

```
def test_has_right_title(self):
    title = self.browser.title
    self.assertEqual('aaa', title)
```

Or refactored to

```
def test_has_right_title(self):
    self.assertEqual('aaa', self.browser.title) # assuming you don't need it anywhere else
```

Comment: thanbks for the response sircapsalot but i get the following... AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'get_title'sircapsalot

Comment: oops! it's actually just driver.title

Comment: Appreciate it!! Thanks

Comment: I was stuck on the same thing. Stackoverflow rules!